# System Monitor : How to display net speed on panel

Tags: 16.04, internet, system-monitor

I use **system monitor** with 16.04 in Unity. Currently, I get all the graphs and text indicator for *Disk* on top panel. I want to have net speed displayed instead of Disk. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 19):

### Xenial

- Install `indicator-netspeed` from terminal
- Run `apt:indicator-netspeed` from your browser's URL panel
- Download **[32-bit](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed/indicator-netspeed_0+git20140722-0~webupd8~xenial_i386.deb)** or **[64-bit](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed/indicator-netspeed_0+git20140722-0~webupd8~xenial_amd64.deb)** deb package from launchpad and install them via Software Center

**Terminal install**

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
apt update && apt install indicator-netspeed
```

To start the indicator, run `indicator-netspeed &`

[image: xenial]

### Bionic and up (with GNOME 3)

**Gnome Extensions: [Install](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/)**

If you want to download the extension package manually, select your shell version and extension version.

**GitHub: [hedayaty/netspeed](https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed)**

[image: bionic]

### Bionic with Unity panel

**Terminal install**

```
sudo -i
apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
apt update && apt install indicator-netspeed-unity
```

To start the indicator, run `indicator-netspeed-unity &`

**Launchpad: [Download](http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed-unity/)**
**GitHub: [ggleb/indicator-netspeed-unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity)**

Comment: how can I use it on Ubuntu Mate

Comment: @blueray just type **apt:mate-netspeed** in your browser's URL panel

Comment: On bionic apt gives `Package netspeed is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source` so unfortunately this is not quite working...

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04 simply open the Ubuntu software app and search for **[Netspeed](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/)**. Click to install the app and it will be displayed on your upper status bar on the right side.

Comment: this does not work in 19.04

Answer (score 4):

#### Unity (Ubuntu 17.04 and below)

Steps to see NetSpeed Indicator n Unity Desktop Ubuntu

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type the below codes in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
   ```
3. Logout of the current session  & Login again for the changes to take effect.
4. Net speed indicator app will start automatically on top of the Unity Panel.

   If you don't like to logout,  you can still start Netspeed Indicator Applet on Unity panel.
5. Open the terminal and type the below code to start the Netspeed indicator app

   ```
   indicator-netspeed &
   ```

That's it. You can see the Upload & download Speed also by clicking on the Icon.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Netspeed for Unity** for that with Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, and think [this link to acquire Netspeed](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-17-10/netspeed-indicator) will be helpful; please note there's a version for 16.04 ('Xenial'), so you can disregard everything on that page but the second and third paragraphs, to wit:

1. `sudo -i`
2. `add-apt-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed`
3. `apt-get update`
4. `apt install indicator-netspeed-unity`
5. Restart your PC/laptop.

Answer (score 0):

#### GNOME Shell (Ubuntu 17.10+)

There are several GNOME extensions. The one with the indicator that I like the most is: [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) (AKA [gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet))

[image: screenshot]

Includes network speed and much more.

#### Alternatives

- [Vitals](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/): Simple. Only numbers (without graphs).

  [image]
- [Freon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/): Only numbers (without graphs).